# GET and set a custom product price on add to cart via URL in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, get, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to pass a parameter to a Woocommerce site using a URL - for instance:

`site/?custom_p=77` will be the URL.

here is my code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
function custom_price( $cprice, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
    wc_delete_product_transients($product->get_id());
    // Get the data from the GET request
$custom_p=$_GET['custom_p'];
    return ($custom_p) ;
}
```

URL add to cart `site/?add-to-cart=455&custom_p=77`

The problem when I declare the number `77` directly it works `$custom_p=77` but `$_GET['custom_p']` declaration gives as a result zero in cart.

Comment: @RST since Woocommerce version 3, woocommerce_get_price is the deprecated hook.

Answer (score 2):

Your GET variables get lost once URL changes, so all product prices get empty because also you are not targeting a the product that has been added to cart.

In this case you need to enable and use a WooCommerce Session variable to store the product ID and the custom price, when a `custom_p` GET variable is detected. Then you can use that WooCommerce Session variable to change the product price.

**First we detect and store the necessary data in a `WC_Session` variable:**

```
// get and set the custom product price in WC_Session
add_action( 'init', 'get_custom_product_price_set_to_session' );
function get_custom_product_price_set_to_session() {
    // Check that there is a 'custom_p' GET variable
    if( isset($_GET['add-to-cart']) && isset($_GET['custom_p']) 
    && $_GET['custom_p'] > 0 && $_GET['add-to-cart'] > 0 ) {
        // Enable customer WC_Session (needed on first add to cart)
        if ( ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
            WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
        }
        // Set the product_id and the custom price in WC_Session variable
        WC()->session->set('custom_p', [
            'id'    => (int) wc_clean($_GET['add-to-cart']),
            'price' => (float) wc_clean($_GET['custom_p']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### Then there is 2 ways to change the price of the product added to cart *(choose only one)*

**Option 1 - Changing the product price directly:**

```
// Change product price from WC_Session data
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_product_price', 900, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_product_price', 900, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_product_price', 900, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_product_price', 900, 2 );
function custom_product_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ( $data = WC()->session->get('custom_p') ) && $product->get_id() == $data['id'] ) {
        $price = $data['price'];
    }
    return $price;
}
```

---

**Option 2 - Change the cart item price:**

```
// Change cart item price from WC_Session data
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_item_price', 20, 1 );
function custom_cart_item_price( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Must be required since Woocommerce version 3.2 for cart items properties changes
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Looo through our specific cart item keys
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get custom product price for the current item
        if ( ( $data = WC()->session->get('custom_p') ) && $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $data['id'] ) {
            // Set the new product price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $data['price'] );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> USAGE URL variables example: `www.example.com/?add-to-cart=37&custom_p=75`

Comment: option 1 works well against option 2 it displays the correct total in the cart but the price is not correct.
thank you so much it's resolved

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 gives a fatal error on WC admin. To fix that, I had to add `!is_admin()` to the if clause so it should look like this:

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_product_price', 900, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_product_price', 900, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_product_price', 900, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_product_price', 900, 2 );
function custom_product_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ( !is_admin() && $data = WC()->session->get('custom_p') ) && $product->get_id() == $data['id'] ) {
        $price = $data['price'];
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice, it works even when dreamweaver says there is a syntax error in the first Part where the WC_Session variable is set:

> ```
>     // Set the product_id and the custom price in WC_Session variable
>     WC()->session->set('custom_p', [
>         'id'    => (int) wc_clean($_GET['add-to-cart']),
>         'price' => (float) wc_clean($_GET['custom_p']),
>     ]);
> ```